# Étymologie du mot 'pillage' et relation avec le mot slave 'pljatška'

Tags: étymologie

En grec on dit *pliatsiko* (*πλιάτσικο*), mot provenant du mot slave *pljatška*. Cherchant pour le mot équivalent français *pillage* je me demande si ce mot a aussi la même étymologie.

Comment: « Pillage » est dérivé de « piller » qui vient lui-même du latin *pilleum*, le Dictionnaire historique de la langue  française (sld A. Rey) dit que le mot latin *pilleum* est rapproché, sans qu'on puisse y voir un emprunt, du grec *pilos* (*πῖλος*).  À l'origine *pilleum* désignait  le bonnet phrygien dont on coiffait les esclaves, puis a désigné un morceau de chiffon.  Voir aussi Wikipedia [Pileus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pileus). Je ne connais pas le grec mais toi tu dois savoir si il y a un rapport entre *pliatsiko* et *pilos*.

Comment: Par ailleurs je ne pense pas que la question telle qu'elle est posée ait sa place sur French Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Pillage » est dérivé de « piller » qui vient lui-même du latin *pilleum*, le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française (sld A. Rey) dit que le mot latin *pilleum* est rapproché, sans qu'on puisse y voir un emprunt, du grec *pilos* (*πῖλος*).

À l'origine *pilleum* désignait le bonnet phrygien dont on coiffait les esclaves, puis a désigné un morceau de chiffon. Voir aussi Wikipedia [Pileus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pileus). Je ne connais pas le grec mais toi tu dois savoir s'il y a un rapport entre *pliatsiko* et *pilos*.